# Android Glide: How to download bitmap at specific size?

Tags: android, bitmap, image-loading, android-glide, image-caching

I'm using Glide to load images on [Scale ImageView](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) - it is a custom view with pan and zoom gestures. I should pass `Bitmap` object to this custom view in order to set picture.

So I can use Glide's `.asBitmap()` with `SimpleTarget`:

```
private SimpleTarget target = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
       scaleImageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap));
    }
};

private void loadImageSimpleTarget() {  
    Glide
        .with(context) 
        .load(url)
        .asBitmap()
        .into(target);
}
```

This code snippet works well, but I will get fullsize Bitmap, which can lead to `OutOfMemoryErrors`. Also I could specify desired Bitmap size on constructor like this: `...new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(250, 250)...`, but I would have to manually calculate dimensions.

Is there a possibility to pass view (instance of CustomView) to Glide's request, so dimensions will calculated automatically and receive Bitmap object as a result?

Comment: you want to use the dimensions of CustomView?

Comment: @leonziyo yes, I want to load images in size of CustomView. I use it with 'match_parent', so it will have specific dimensions.

Comment: why don't you pass the dimension to `SimpleTarget`'s constructor. Like this: `new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(customView.getWidth(), customView.getHeight())`...

Comment: @leonziyo basically because it returns 0 when I call `customView.getWidth`. I call it from `onCreateView` inside Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing the discussion from the comments, you get 0 for width and height when calling it from `onCreateView`. However, you can set a listener to be notified when the bounds of the view are actually calculated and then you can get the real width and height by calling `getWidth` or `getHeight`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...
    // your other stuff
    // ...

    // set listener
    customView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Log.d("debug", "width after = " + customView.getHeight());

            // pass the width and height now that it is available
            target = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(customView.getWidth(), customView.getHeight()) {  
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                   scaleImageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap));
                }
            };

            // remove listener, we don't need to be notified again.
            customView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```